# Integration type problem

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x$) be continuous, positive function such that $f(–x) = g(x) – 1$,$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(-x)}$ and $\int\limits_{ - 20}^{20} {f\left( x \right)dx}  = 2020$
then the value of is $\int\limits_{ - 20}^{20} {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}}dx} $ is

(A) 1010

(B) 1050

(C) 2020

(D) 2050

My approach is as follow

GIven $f\left( { - x} \right) = g\left( x \right) - 1\& f\left( x \right) = \frac{{g\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( { - x} \right)}}$

$\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}} = \frac{1}{{g\left( { - x} \right)}}\& f\left( { - x} \right) = g\left( x \right) - 1 \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) + 1 = g\left( { - x} \right) \Rightarrow \frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}} = \frac{1}{{f\left( x \right) + 1}}$

$\int\limits_{ - 20}^{20} {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}}dx}  \Rightarrow \int\limits_{ - 20}^{20} {\frac{1}{{f\left( x \right) + 1}}dx} $

Not able to approach from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So firstly we make the computation

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{g(-x)}=\frac{1}{1+f(x)}.$$

Now notice that

$$\int_{-20}^{20}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-20}^{20} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}=\int_{-20}^{0} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}+\int_{0}^{20} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}=\int_{0}^{20} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(-x)}+\int_{0}^{20} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}=\int_0^{20}\frac{2+f(x)+f(-x)}{1+f(x)+f(-x)+f(x)f(-x)}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

However using the fact that $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(-x)}$, we can easily see that

$$f(x)f(-x)=1,$$

and so

$$\int_{-20}^{20} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{20}\frac{2+f(x)+f(-x)}{2+f(x)+f(-x)}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{20}\mathrm{d}x=20.$$

So either there is a mistake in my computation, or none of the answers are correct.

Answer (score 3):

The hypothesis are incompatible:

$\frac{g(-x)}{g(x)}=f(-x)=g(x)-1\Rightarrow g(x)=\sqrt{g(x)+g(-x)}=g(-x)\Rightarrow f(x)=1$, but $\int_{-20}^{20}1\,\mathrm dx\ne2020.$

Comment: So one could say that all answers are vacuously true ;-)